# I keep getting this error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to run this command, but, everytime I do, I keep getting this error: "list indices must be integers or slices". Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
skins = ""
data = requests.get("https://benbotfn.tk/api/v1/cosmetics/br").json()["items"]
for x in data:
    if x["backendType"] == "AthenaCharacter":
      skins = skins + x["name"] + ":" + "\n"  + x["id"] + "\n"
if skins == "":
  skins = "None"

@client.command()
async def skin(ctx):
  await ctx.send(skins)
```

Comment: Try to print what `.json()` method returns. Most probably it would be a `list`. If yes the error is clear, "You cannot index a list with an object of type string"

Comment: What is `data`? You should always include a minimal example of the data - enough to  reproduce the problem. Please read [mre].  When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Your problem is that x is a list and you are treating it like a dictionary

Comment: `"https://benbotfn.tk/api/v1/cosmetics/br"` returns a list, not a dict so you get this error. Also, there is no "item" key in any of your data. `data` is a list and `x` is a dict

Answer (score 1):

The way you took the data is wrong is should be like this and inside the command it self. keep in mind you will get an error if you run this, you can't send messages longer than 2000 character.

```py
@bot.command()
async def skin(ctx):
    skins = []
    for x in data:
        if x["backendType"] == "AthenaCharacter":
            skins.append(f'{x["name"]}: {x["id"]}')

    print(skins[0:3]) # just to show it works print the first elements 

    await ctx.send('\n'.join(skins))
```